# How to create a function in Kivy that is callable by two sliders? How should the arguments look like?

Tags: python, callback, kivy

I am trying to update a label in Kivy with the value of two sliders summed up. But I can
't figure out how the function arguments should look like.

My class has two properties `self.temp1` and `self.temp2` and two sliders that are created like this:

```
self.slider1 = Slider(min=-20, max=60, step=0.1, value = self.temp1)
self.slider2 = Slider(min=-20, max=60, step=0.1, value = self.temp2)
self.slider1.bind(value = self.update_temperature1)
self.slider2.bind(value = self.update_temperature2)
```

And I want to update a label, with the `update_temperature` function. I got a solution by using two function, for each slider.

```
def update_temperature1(self, instance, t1):
    self.temp1 = t1
    self.label1.text = str("%3.1F" % (t1 + self.temp2))

def update_temperature2(self, instance, t2):
    self.temp2 = t2
    self.label1.text = str("%3.1F" % (t2 + self.temp1))
```

I want to create a single function, but I get errors at the `slider.bind` when I try something like this:

```
self.slider1.bind(value = self.update_temperature)
self.slider2.bind(value = self.update_temperature)

def update_temperature(self, instance, t1, t2):
    self.temp1 = t1
    self.temp2 = t2
    self.label1.text = str("%3.1F" % (self.temp1 + self.temp2))
```

How should I do this? Is there a better approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day. In the `update_temperature` callback, did you insert the argument for t1 and t2? If you cannot, I recomment you rearrange the data flow.

```
temp1 = -20 #default
temp2 = -20 #default
self.slider1 = Slider(min=-20, max=60, step=0.1, value = self.temp1)
self.slider2 = Slider(min=-20, max=60, step=0.1, value = self.temp2)
self.slider1.bind(value = self.update_temperature)
self.slider2.bind(value = self.update_temperature)

....

def update_temperature(self, instance, temp):
    #update temperature accordingly
    if instance is self.slider1:
        self.temp1 = temp
    elif instance is self.slider2:
        self.temp2 = temp
    #update label text
    self.label1.text = str("%3.1F" % (self.temp1 + self.temp2))
```

Comment: Hello! Oh wow, didn't even think about checking the instance in the 'update_temperature' function. That works great.

As for t1 and t2 arguments, I tried something like this: 
'
        self.slider1.bind(value = self.update_temperature, t1=self.slider1.value, t2=self.temp2)
        self.slider2.bind(value = self.update_temperature, t1=self.temp1,   t2=self.slider2.value)
'
But I get a 'AssertionError: 10 is not callable' where 10 is the value of 'self.temp1'.